# CheckboxGroupInput in 2nd tab not getting updated, while first one works fine

Tags: r, shiny

I am making the user upload multiple excel files and then updating the checkboxgroupinputs file_num and file_num_2. These were created using UIoutput. The two checkboxgroupinputs are in different tabs. The input in the first tab (file_num) gets updated correctly on uploading the excel file, but the input in the second tab (file_num_2) doesn't get updated, even though the ui of the checkbox is created at the initial start of the app. Also, replacing file_num_2 with file_num in the output of the 2nd tab made the app unresponsive. Both the UI checkboxes use the same code for creation and updating, and differ only in their id. Is the problem related to the fact that the 2nd checkbox is in another tab? What could have caused the problem?

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(here)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(checkmate)
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test App "),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        "Sample Data",
        fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 9,
            fileInput("file_1", "Please choose Excel file", multiple = TRUE, accept = ".xlsx", buttonLabel = "Browse"),
                        
            
            
          ),
        
          column(
            width = 3,
            uiOutput("Variables")
          )
        )
      ),
      
      tabPanel(
        "Comparison Panel",
        uiOutput("Variables_2")

        
      )
      
      
    )
    
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  files_list_creator_1 <- reactive({
    files_list <- list()
    for (paths in input$file_1$datapath){ 
      file_to_add <- as.data.frame(read_excel(paths))
      print(as.data.frame(read_excel(paths)))
      files_list <- append(files_list, list(file_to_add))
    
    }
    return(files_list) 
    
  })
#--------------------------------------------  
  output$Variables <- renderUI({
    req(files_list_creator_1())
    numVar <- asInt(length(files_list_creator_1()))
    print(numVar)
    
    taglist = list(radioButtons(inputId = "file_num", label ="File number", choices = c("Choices will appear here")))
    tagList(taglist) 
    
  })
#---------------------------------------------------------  
  observeEvent(input$file_1,{ 
    req(files_list_creator_1()) 
    updateRadioButtons(
      session, 
      "file_num",
      choiceNames = input$file_1$name,
      choiceValues = as.character(1:length(files_list_creator_1())), 
      selected = as.character(1) 
    )
    
  })

  output$Variables_2 <- renderUI({
    req(files_list_creator_1())
    numVar <- asInt(length(files_list_creator_1()))
    
    taglist = list(checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "file_num_2", label ="File number 2", choices = c("Choices will appear here")))
    taglist = append(taglist, list(checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "variables_to_plot" , label = "Variables", choices = c("Choices will appear here"))))
    
    tagList(taglist) 
    
  })
  
#-------------------------------------------
  
  observeEvent(input$file_1,{ 
    req(files_list_creator_1()) 
    # print(files_list_creator_1()[[1]])
    # print("Hello")
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(
      session, 
      "file_num_2",
      choiceNames = input$file_1$name,
      choiceValues = as.character(1:length(files_list_creator_1())), 
      selected = as.character(1)
      
    )
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(
      session, 
      "variables_to_plot",
      choiceNames = input$file_1$name,
      choiceValues = as.character(1:length(files_list_creator_1())), 
      selected = as.character(1)
      
    )
```

Comment: Please make your code reproducible by including it all.  You're missing the closing brace of your final `observeEvent`, the closing brace of your server function and the call to `shinyApp`.  You may need `suspendWhenHidden = TRUE`.  See [here](https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/0.11/outputoptions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess was wrong.  The problem is that your `output$Variables_2` is `render`ed when you switch tabs.  (You can check this by putting a `print("Some helpful string")` immediately after the call to `req`.) Your version of this function inserts the placeholder text in the `file_num_2` `checkboxGroupInput`.

There's no need for a call to `outputOptions`.  This code appears to give you what I think you want.

```
 output$Variables_2 <- renderUI({
    req(files_list_creator_1())

    numVar <- as.integer(length(files_list_creator_1()))
    
    if (length(files_list_creator_1()) == 0) {
      taglist = list(
        checkboxGroupInput(
          inputId = "file_num_2", 
          label ="File number 2", 
          choices = c("Choices will appear here")
        )
      )
    } else {
      taglist = list(
        checkboxGroupInput(
          inputId = "file_num_2", 
          label ="File number 2", 
          choiceNames = input$file_1$name,
          choiceValues = as.character(1:length(files_list_creator_1())), 
          selected = as.character(1)
        )
      )
    }
    taglist = append(
      taglist, 
      list(
        checkboxGroupInput(
          inputId = "variables_to_plot" , 
          label = "Variables", 
          choices = c("Choices will appear here")
        )
      )
     )
     tagList(taglist) 
  })
```